# spring mvc url formatting

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc. I have 3 pages in my site (actually the controller handle those requests):

```
localhost/post.html
localhost/search.html
localhost/list.html
```

I would like the url to be `localhost/XXX/post.html` where `XXX` is a parameter that will transffered as a parameter to the controller method. For example, if the user asks `localhost/bla/post.html` then the controller method of `/post` will get `bla` as parameter.

Is this possible in spring mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and quite easy to do.  When you define the mapping for the handler URL you can put a variable into the path like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/{blah}/post.html")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(@PathVariable("blah") String blah) {
  //
}
```

Spring will set the value of the String for you when it calls the method.

(While not strictly necessary, it is also normal to have a subdirectory for the dispatcher servlet in your paths.  Mapping a dispatcher to the root can be a pain.  Messes up static resource access, for example.  e.g., localhost/myapp/blah/post.html)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand your last recommendation about the dispatcher servlet. I don't want users of my site to surf to domain/myapp/post.html. I would like them to surf domain/post.html (or domain/XXX/post.html)

Comment: in web.xml, avoid mapping a org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet to /*.  Things will be easier as the app grows if you map it down a level to /app/* or something.  Apache or IIS on the frontend can rewrite pretty public URLs into whatever.

Comment: But then the user should enter domain/app/post.html instead of domain/post.html.

Comment: If you've exposed a JavaEE App server directly to the internet, yes, but you don't want to do that anyway, do you? :)

Answer (score 0):

In JSF it may be done with [PrettyFaces library](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/). May be it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

It easy can be done using annotations:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(@PathVariable("id") String id)
    {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String search(@PathVariable("id") String id)
    {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(@PathVariable("id") String id)
    {
    }

}
```